# Azure function with managed identity running on Visual Studio throwing error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I am running an azure function with Service Bus trigger on Visual Studio. I have added my account (using email) in Visual Studio 2022 using `Tools > Options > Azure Service Authentication`. I have added this user account in Azure service bus using `Access Control (IAM)` and given it `Azure Service Bus Data Sender & receiver` roles.

This is what the Azure function looks like:

```
[FunctionName("FunctionWthMI")]
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic-one", "sub-one", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]string mySbMsg)
{
    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

This is how the setting looks:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "ServiceBusConnection:fullyQualifiedNamespace": "sb-test-three.servicebus.windows.net",
        "ServiceBusConnString": "Endpoint=sb://sb-test-three.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=ManagedIdentity",
        "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://sb-test-three.servicebus.windows.net/;Authentication=Managed Identity"
    }
}
```

I followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2#connect-to-service-bus-in-your-function-app to set ServiceBus Connection string.

[image]

After running the app I am getting following error:

> Timestamp: 2022-10-01 15:16:01Z'.) (Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot) (Azure CLI not installed) (Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.). System.Private.CoreLib: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot

I have installed Azure-CLI locally along with Azure function core tools on my machine.

I have logged out and logged into Visual Studio subscription.

Comment: have you tried `ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace` locally ? It happened to work for me

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, as lot of articles suggested it. I get following error: `[2022-10-01T20:58:35.681Z] Timestamp: 2022-10-01 20:58:18Z'.) (Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot) (Please run 'az login' to set up account) (Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.). System.Private.CoreLib: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. 
`

Comment: @Thomas: is your use case same ? where you are trying to access service bus topic messages using azure function with managed identity ? If yes, can you please share more details as the answer this question.

Comment: looks like your credential have expired ? Can you check in Tools > Options > Azure Service Authentication ? If expired, you should see a message saying re-enter your credentials

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you for suggestion. Token is not expired. I also logged out and logged in back and no luck.